# Python - Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

just doing an edabit challenge and I am stuck and how to get this code to pass all tests: Goal is to remove all "special" characters (e.g. ! @ # $ % ^ & \ *) and returns the new string. The only non-alphanumeric characters allowed are dashes -, underscores _ and spaces." My code below is having two issues: 1) It appears that it will not work for test cases that have "!" even though I have it in my list of patterns to look for. 2) I cant find a way to have it not take out "-,_,  " if I use re.sub(r'[\w]',"",txt).

```
def remove_special_characters(txt):
    import re
    x = re.sub(r'[!@#$%^&\*\(\)]',"",txt)
    return x
```

Comment: You may want to specify the negation of what you want instead of the list of what you do not want: `r"[^\w\s-_]+"`. Do you want to keep tabs as well?

Comment: Why not just `re.sub(r'[^\w- ]', '', txt)`?

Comment: @LevZakharov Because spaces, dashes, and underscores must not be removed.

Comment: Could you provide an input that fails? Because your regex should work as you described (it removes `!`). But ultimately, you should use a negation if you have a set of known allowed chars and an unknown set of disallowed.

Comment: @DYZ `\w` contains underscore.

Comment: @LevZakharov There is still an open issue of tabs.

Comment: hello all, view below my solution, but I know it could be cleaner. Just seraching for a way to have logic like ( remove all special characters (something like \w) Except for dashes, underscores spaces)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all special characters (something like \w) except for dashes, underscores spaces:

```
import re
def remove_special_characters(txt):
    x = re.sub('[^\w\-_\s]', '', txt)
    return x
```

Comment: No need to escape metachars inside brackets (except `^` and `-` if given as first).

Comment: So this almost worked, but needed a lot more special characters:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.punctuation` - returns a String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters.

```
import string
print string.punctuation # Returns '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

and then you can use `re.sub` to substitute like

```
print re.sub(r'['+string.punctuation+']', '',text)
```

Comment: the problem is that string.puncuation takes out dashes, spaces and underscores, I have to leave those in , that is what I dont know how to do

Comment: Then probably you should try this :-
`''.join( c for c in line if  c not in '{chars you don't want}' )`

Answer (score 0):

This solution, with all your help worked:

```
def remove_special_characters(txt):
    pattern = '!@#$%^&*()\\.+[]={}<>~`?,|'
    import re
    x = re.sub('[' + re.escape(pattern) + ']', '', txt)
    return x
```